# On the Joukowsky map

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

Let $\rho>1$ and $E_\rho$ be the interior of the ellipse $\Gamma: \frac{1}{2}(\rho e^{it}+\rho^{-1} e^{-it}), \quad t \in[0,2\pi]$. Let $A_\rho = \{z: \rho^{-1} < |z| < \rho\}$.

Consider the Joukowsky map $J(z)=\frac{1}{2}(z+z^{-1})$.

I am reading a book where the author says:

> For each $\xi \in E_\rho \backslash[-1,1]$ there are two corresponding
>   values of $z \in A_{\rho}$ which are inverses of one another s.t.
>   $J(z)=\xi$.

Why is the line $[-1,1]$ removed? Why is it special? I guess the same statement holds also for $\xi \in [-1,1]$, because we can write $\xi = \frac{1}{2}( e^{it}+e^{-it})$ then $\xi = J(e^{it})=J(e^{-it})$.

Don't we have $J(A_\rho) = E_\rho$?.

Comment: @JeanMarie but even for the point $0$ we have two distinct points $J(i)=J(-i)=0$. So still I am not getting the point.

Comment: You are right. I erase my first comment which is erroneous.